# Xcode compiler keeps crashing on a class that has a dictionary with a lot of elements

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Compiler keeps crashing with a "Segmentation fault 11" on a class that has a dictionary with over 40 thousand value pairs defined. If I would reduce the amount of lines it works. There are no duplicate keys.

I understand it's an Xcode bug, but perhaps there is a known workaround?

```
class Rates {
    let array:[Int:Double] = [
        99502:0.1730,
        99503:0.1730,
        99504:0.1730,
// 42000 lines, defining other value pairs are here
        83414:0.0837
    ]

    subscript(index: Int) -> Double? {
        return self.array[index]
    }
}
```

Comment: Well how about splitting the dict into multiple ones?

Comment: there would be too many..

Comment: For how many pairs does it work? Have you checked that?

Comment: it's inconsistent, but not more than a thousand

Comment: Load your values from a data file

Comment: yes, that is what I was trying to avoid

Comment: why? Include the file in your project so it will be in the bundle and use a simple parser to get your values.

Comment: thank you, I understand, but it's not the workaround kind that I meant originally.

Comment: @paul Make sure you file a radar about this with Apple, with this code as a test case.